# Looping on rows of a data.table in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table

**Given a data.table as defined below**

```
set.seed(123) 
ds <- data.table(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10))
```

What is the recommended way to loop on rows of the data.table and get a vector of the amount of the values in every column of each row that is between some range, e.g. -0.5 and 0.5, avoiding using for()?

And get some type of this answer

```
for (i in 1:10) {
   print(sum(-0.5 < ds[i] & ds[i] < 0.5))
}
```

And if I wanted to apply it only on some specific columns which are defined in on vector, like:

```
cols <- c(1,3)
```

and get the same type of answer?

```
for (i in 1:10) {
   print(sum(-0.5 < ds[i,cols,with=F] & ds[i,cols,with=F] < 0.5))
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
ds[, Reduce('+', lapply(.SD, function(x) -0.5 < x & x < 0.5))]
#[1] 0 3 1 2 1 0 2 1 0 2
```

You can supply columns you like via `.SDcols`:

```
ds[, Reduce('+', lapply(.SD, function(x) -0.5 < x & x < 0.5)), .SDcols = cols]
#[1] 0 2 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: Also: `rowSums(between(ds, -0.5, 0.5, FALSE))`

Comment: @Arun yep - my aim was avoiding extra conversions to matrix, to stay a little faster

Comment: `>` and `<` are primitives which result in a matrix on the whole, from `between()`. The `data.table` isn't being coerced to `matrix` during `rowSums()`, if that's what you mean..

Comment: @Arun try timing just the `between` part vs the above for `N = 1e7; ds <- data.table(x = rnorm(N), y = rnorm(N), z = rnorm(N))`

Comment: Okay thanks. Will move this to C to see if we can gain some performance.